# Input value between x and y

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, user-input

So I need to gather input from a user but I have to ensure that they can only enter a number between 1 and 0 before the program accepts their input.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
def user_input():
    try:

        initial_input = float(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 0"))

    except ValueError:

        print("Please try again, it must be a number between 0 and 1")
        user_input()
```

Could someone edit this or explain to me how I can add another rule as well as the `ValueError` so that it only accepts numbers between 1 and 0?

Answer (score 5):

You can't check the value in the same line as you catch the exception.
Try this:

```
def user_input():
    while True:
        initial_input = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 0")
        if initial_input.isnumeric() and (0.0 <= float(initial_input) <= 1.0):
            return float(initial_input)
        print("Please try again, it must be a number between 0 and 1")
```

**EDIT**
Removed the try/except and used `isnumeric()`instead.